# Not able to generate Index using SOLR 4.2 configurations

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, solr4

I am generating employee details index using Solr 3.3 & Tomcat 7 setup. However I would like to try this with newer version of Solr 4.2.

I've created new setup for this in:  `d:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19\solr_4_2\collection1\`

I've the following directories there:

1. `bin`
2. in `conf` >> `solrconfig.xml`, `schema.xml`, `data-config.xml`, `scripts.conf` & `zoo.cfg` files are there.
3. in `lib`  >>
   `hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar`, `solr-4.2.0.war`, `solr-dataimporthandler-4.2.0.jar`, `solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.2.0.jar` files are there.

in `data-config.xml` below tags are there.

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb://127.0.0.1;databaseName=EMP" user="sa" password="pass"/>
<document  name="EMPLOYEE">
   <entity name="COMMON" query="select type,title,name,empid from employee" > 
   <field column="type" name="type"/> 
   <field column="title" name="title"/> 
   <field column="name" name="name"/> 
   <field column="empid" name="empid"/> 
  </entity> 
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I'm using dataimport command `http://localhost:8080/solr_4_2/dataimport?command=full-import` getting index failed. Below are the errors.

```
SEVERE: Exception while processing: EMPLOYEE document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select type,title,name,empid from employee Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:465)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:404)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:319)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:227)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: **File input/output error //127.0.0.1.properties java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\127.0.0.1.properties.new** (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:127)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:366)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: somewhat similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412871/grails-deployment-issues-war-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Your URL connection string is somehow incorrect. You are providing a network address but it gets parsed as a file name. [Double check](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html) the correct connection string for server-based connection.